# Convergence to zero in total variation: Seeking a contradiction

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, bounded-variation, geometric-measure-theory, total-variation

Suppose I have a compact measurable set $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ and a sequence of functions $\{f_k\}_{k=1}^\infty\subset C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ with the following set of properties:

1. $f_k\geq0$
2. $\int_{\mathbb R^n} f_k\rightarrow0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$
3. $f_k|_{\mathbb R^n\backslash\Omega}\equiv0$
4. $\mathrm{TV}(f_k)\rightarrow0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$
5. $f_k(x_k)>1$ for some $x_k\in\Omega$

**Is it possible to prove that there is a contradiction?**

In particular, the vanishing total variation (property 4) "wants" $f_k$ to decay slowly away from $x_k$ , but properties 1, 2, and 3 together imply that $f_k$ should be close to zero; somehow these seem to contradict.

Here, I am using the definition of total variation $$\mathrm{TV}(f):=\sup_{\|\phi\|_\infty\leq1}\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x)\nabla\cdot\phi(x)\,dx.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless $n=1$, the total variation does not constrain pointwise values. There is no contradiction.

A sequence with all these properties is $f_k(x)=f(kx)$ where $f$ is nonnegative, smooth and compactly supported with $f(0)>1$. Indeed, $TV(f_k)=k^{1-n}TV(f)\to 0$ via a change of variable.

Comment: Shucks!  You're right, not sure how I missed that.  Back to the drawing board for me :-( --- stuck proving what I thought would be a footnote in a paper, a property I'm 99% sure is true but apparently not for this reason!

Comment: BTW, here's a revised question that I think is better posed:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2888133/minimizing-total-variation-with-small-norm-in-a-compact-set