# Minimizing total variation with small norm in a compact set

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, bounded-variation, geometric-measure-theory, total-variation

Take $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ to be compact.  Suppose for $t>0$ we define $f$ via the variational problem
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\inf_{f\in\mathrm{BV}(\mathbb R^n)} & \mathrm{TV}[f]\\
\textrm{s.t.} & f\geq0\\
& f\equiv0\textrm{ on }\mathbb R^n\backslash\Omega\\
& \int_{\mathbb R^n} f=t.
\end{array}
$$
**Is it possible to show that there exists a minimizer $f$ that satisfies $\sup_{x\in\mathbb R^n}f(x)\leq1$ for sufficiently small $t>0$?**

My first attempt to do this in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2888106/convergence-to-zero-in-total-variation-seeking-a-contradiction) is obviously incorrect!  This fact seems obviously true but I'm missing something.

Here, I am using the definition of total variation $$\mathrm{TV}(f):=\sup_{\|\phi\|_\infty\leq1}\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x)\nabla\cdot\phi(x)\,dx.$$

UPDATE:  It is clear that the above statement is true if and only if the $t=1$ solution admits a bounded function as its minimizer.  But it seems to be nontrivial to show the latter.

Comment: Are you looking for functions in $BV(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: Yes. See solution below, unless I missed something

Comment: ...I missed something :-)

Comment: We were able to prove this and many related facts in our paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.07943 — thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t=1$ and let $u$ be a minimizer. Let $m(r):=\mathcal{L}^n(\{u\geq r\})$, and suppose by contradiction $u$ is not bounded, that is $m(r)>0$ for every positive $r$. For positive $R$ define the truncation $u_R:=\inf\{u,R\}$ and then define the competitor $v_R=\tfrac{u_R}{\|u_R\|_1}$. By coarea
$$TV(v_R)=\frac{1}{\|u_R\|_1}\int_0^R P(\{u\geq r\})dr.$$
By coarea again and by the isoperimetric inequality
\begin{align}
TV(u)&=\int_0^\infty P(\{u\geq r\})dr\\
&=\|u_R\|_1 TV(v_R)+\int_R^\infty P(\{u\geq r\})dr\\
&\geq \|u_R\|_1 TV(v_R)+c_n\int_{R}^\infty m(r)^{1-\frac{1}{n}}dr\\
&\geq \|u_R\|_1 TV(v_R)+\frac{c_n}{m(R)^\frac{1}{n}}\int_{R}^\infty m(r)dr\\
&=\|u_R\|_1 TV(v_R)+c_n\frac{1-\|u_R\|_1}{m(R)^\frac{1}{n}}.
\end{align}
Now from the minimality property of $u$ we obtain
$$TV(v_R)\geq TV(u)\geq \|u_R\|_1 TV(v_R)+c_n\frac{1-\|u_R\|_1}{m(R)^\frac{1}{n}} $$
that is
$$TV(v_R)\geq \frac{c_n}{m(R)^\frac{1}{n}}$$
(here we are dividing by $1-\|u_R\|_1$ and we are using the unboundedness assumption to make sure this is non-zero). But this is a contradiction because $m(R)$ goes to zero as $R\to\infty$, while $TV(v_R)$ stays bounded because 
$$TV(v_R)=\frac{1}{\|u_R\|_1}TV(u_R)\leq \frac{1}{\|u_R\|_1}TV(u)\leq 2 \,TV(u) $$
if we choose $R$ big enough so that $\|u_R\|_1\geq \tfrac12$. Therefore $u$ can not be unbounded.

Being more careful you can also find a quantitative bound on $\|u\|_\infty$ in terms of $t$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! We were able to identify a similar proof of this fact which is in the paper we recently posted: https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.07943 — hopefully this one looks alright too!

Answer (score 1):

The existence of a minimizer is easy, but I don't know how to prove boundness: take $B$ an open ball which contains the $\Omega$. It is easy to see that, since you are asking that $f$ vanishes outside $\Omega$, you can as well minimize the total variation over $B$. Take a minimizing sequence $f_n$. It is clear that
$$
\sup TV(f_n) < \infty
$$
So that, since $B$ is bounded smooth, you can extract a subseqence $f_{n_k} \to f$ in $L^1(B)$, with $f \in BV(B)$. The lower semicontinuity of the total variation gives:
$$\liminf_k TV(f_{n_k}) \ge TV(f)$$
The first and the second conditons are easy to check.

Comment: To make sure I follow, this shows that a minimizer exists but not that it is bounded, right?  And in order for my claim to be true I'd need this boundedness property?

To show boundedness does it help to know that when t=0 the solution is obviously f=0?

Comment: Yes. I don't think knowing $f=0$ is a minimizer helps

Comment: Hmm!  In the $t=1$ case, essentially the constraints are just saying that $f$ is a probability measure compactly supported in $\Omega$.  So intuitively we're seeking the min over probability measures of TV, with the constraint that they're supported in $\Omega$.

Comment: $W^{1,1}$ is the space of absolutely continuous functions, so since $\Omega$ is compact this would prove what I need, right?  I'm totally OK with adding assumptions on $\Omega$ if this makes the problem easier --- might you have pointers to what I should look at?  (I really appreciate your help --- this is quite distant from my usual area of math!)

Comment: Shucks!  Indeed $n\geq2$ is the case I'm interested in.

Comment: I was wrong you can't get a minimizer in $W^{1,1}$ sorry

Answer (score 0):

Oops! This is an easy problem. The solution scales linearly with $t$, so obviously we can obtain $f$ as small as we want by scaling the $t=1$ case.

Sorry for posting something so straightforward!

EDIT:  This is true only if a bounded solution exists.

Comment: That's assuming there exists a minimizer, and that minimizer is a bounded function. (Which should be true. I think the minimizer is just $c\chi_B$ for some $c>0$ and some ball $B$, which should be provable by coarea formula + isoperimetric inequality).

Comment: True. So the only hard part is showing that there is a minimizer that is a bounded function. Your guess seems reasonable for a solution although numerically I don’t get circles when I solve in 2d.